# Error occur when project create SageMaker MLOps Project Walkthrough Using Third-party Git Repos in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, mlops

i tried to SageMaker MLOps Project Walkthrough Using Third-party Git Repos using AWS pipline. I am begginer in AWS. But always It shows

'Studio encountered an error when creating your project. Try recreating the project again.

User: arn:aws:sts::494026973566:assumed-role/AmazonSageMakerServiceCatalogProductsLaunchRole/servicecatalog is not authorized to perform: sagemaker:AddTags on resource: arn:aws:sagemaker:ap-south-1:494026973566:code-repository/sagemaker-p-vumrjwtu29ap-modelbuild because no identity-based policy allows the sagemaker:AddTags action (Service: AmazonSageMaker; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: a187898b-91b3-4b7a-aa9f-48bafc293dac; Proxy: null)'

I include the image as well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmiSN.jpg)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git per se, it's strictly a permissions issue on your Amazon server. (I don't know precisely what permissions are required but see the error message.)

Comment: Ok sure and Thank you for replying

Answer (score 1):

went away after adding an **inline `sagemaker:AddTags` policy** to the AWS provided `AmazonSageMakerServiceCatalogProducts` Policy

I believe it is an isolated incident. And the problem could be over at GitHub such as it is being protected,

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the role that is used by ServiceCatalog has a policy to allow `sagemaker:AddTags`.

You can go to the IAM console, look up the role that is listed in the error message, and add `sagemaker:AddTags` to the list of `Actions` in the policy.